# Поиск вариации изображения на другом изображении C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

На большом изображении (снимок экрана) есть множество разных мелких изображений, каждое из которых на момент снимка экрана может быть в одном из состояний (кадров). Необходимо найти X,Y координаты каждого из мелких изображений на большом изображении. Очевидно, что это можно сделать по принципу брутфорса, т.е. перебирая каждый пиксель большого изображения и сравнивая с каждым из возможных состояний (Количество мелких изображений * количество кадров) - но это очень долгий и плохой вариант - поэтому, надеюсь кто нибудь подскажет более красивый и быстрый алгоритм решения данной задачи.

Важные оговорки:

1. при решении данной задачи предполагается, что каждый кадр каждого мелкого изображения известен (есть в виде отдельного файла-картинки), и при появлении на большом изображении он не поворачивается и не масштабируется.
2. нет надобности устанавливать какое именно это изображение - важны лишь координаты на большом изображении.
3. Программа пишется на C#, но принципиально я ищу не готовый код, а описание алгоритма действия, так что язык в принципе не важен, в идеале это вообще последовательность действий не привязанная к какому либо языку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, классически задача решается через перебор всех изображений и сложность у нее соответствующая. Но можно существенно упростить задачу и для этого есть пара методов (и их можно применять комбинированно).

- Изображение можно перевести в монохромных вид. По одному байту на пиксель. В этом режиме сравнение будет идти сильно быстрее. А когда будет найдено совпадение, то всегда можно "перепроверить по полноцветной копии".
- Нет нужды для каждого пикселя сравнивать по очереди все изображения. Можно пройтись по всем картинкам, вычитать первые 8-16 пикселей и запомнить. Потом с них построить дерево. Теперь достаточно продвигаться "окном" по исходному изображению и сравнивать. Если первые байты совпали, то есть смысл проверить всю картинку. Если правильно сделать буфер для пикселей (побайтовых), то пробежка по всему изображению может быть почти O(n), если заданные картинки не найдены. А если почитать алгоритм КМП (Кнута-Мориса-Прайта для поиска подстроки в строке) и правильно составить суффиксы для поиска, то можно ещё быстрее делать.

Я в свое время решал очень похожую задачу, нужно было сравнивать две картинки и определять, не было ли сдвига части изображения (кстати, это классическая задача, которую решает MPEG2 или MPEG4 кодер) и перевод картинки в однобайтовое представления очень сильно ускорял - процесс. Но я пошел ещё дальше - я делал упаковку одинаковых байт (такое себе RLE).