# Поиск изображения на диске по изображению из интернета

Tags: c#, c++

Возникла необходимость поиска изображений на жестком диске по загрузке в программу аналогичного изображения. Проще говоря поиск идентичной/очень похожей картинки (могут отличаться степенью сжатия).

В маленьком магазине в соц.сетях - каталог представлен картинками в альбомах. Сами товары для производства требуют файлы, которые хранятся на жестком диске вместе с теми же картинками. Сейчас каталог стал очень большим и ориентироваться в нем, находя нужный заказ по фото очень сложно.

Подскажите, насколько это оптимальный способ решения проблемы? Какими библиотеками посоветуете воспользоваться? Есть небольшой опыт на C# и плюсах.

Comment: Рассматривается ли вариант "есть картинка, чутка обрезанная - но её тоже нужно находить"?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/812762/184217 - посмотрите это. И это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542012/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - да, суть очень схожа, уже просмотрел несколько подобных решений - пишу пробный код. Спасибо.

Comment: @AK, да, обратил внимание на подобные решения. Благодарю)